# Issue with Multipart getParameter

Tags: java, apache-commons-fileupload

I am sending this request on servlet from client side:

at client side I'm doing:
                 img = Capture.capturePhoto(200, 200);

```
        InfiniteProgress inf = new InfiniteProgress();            
        Dialog progress = inf.showInifiniteBlocking(); 
        MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();

        request.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/Test/Test");//calling servlet

          request.addData("ImageName.jpg", img, "image/jpeg");
          request.addArgument("imgname", "image1");


        request.setDisposeOnCompletion(progress);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
```

On the server side I'm using this:

```
a = req.getParameter("imgname");// but value I'm getting is null 
File repository = new File ("F:/SERVLET images");
System.out.println(repository);
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(1024, repository);
((DiskFileItemFactory) factory).setRepository(repository);
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

try
{
    items = upload.parseRequest(req);
}
catch (FileUploadException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext())
{
    FileItem item = iter.next();
    File f1 = new File ("F:/SERVLET images/pics/'"+a+"'.jpg");
    // 'null'.jpg is Printing and image is not displaying   
    try
    {
        item.write(f1);
        System.out.print(f1);
    }
}
```

What did I get wrong?

Comment: Give details about what issue you are getting (Exception or what)

Comment: Yeah, what is the issue? What isn't working?

Comment: are you trying to upload file from browser?

Comment: The way you handle parameters is completely wrong (line 1). Read the documentation, section 'Processing the uploaded items': http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

Comment: Basically I'm using Codename one  for mobile application, the problem I'm facing is getting null value on server side.

Comment: Problem is not with image uploading, when I'm doing 
File f1 = new File ("F:/SERVLET images/pics/img.jpg");
It's working Fine .
But I want to getParameter from user. I think I'm getting wrong with method .